# .Net program executed from ASP page

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp-classic

I have a program in .net (VB .Net) that calls to Excel and Word. It takes a lot of time to complete all the tasks (it reads many logs, export the data to excel, create graphics and then import the graphics to a word template).

My first solution was to include the program as a .dll in the ASP website, but now I´ve dismissed. The program has a high CPU usage, and it may take hours to do all the tasks. A web page must run processes with low CPU usage and/or swift proccesses.

Now I have 2 options:

**A)** Execute the program from ASP:

```
set WshShell = server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
wshShell.Run program
```

**B)** Convert the program in a windows service, and execute the routine (that read logs, export data to excel, create graphic...) sending a message through MSMQ.

I´ve two questions:

**- First:** Are these "good" solutions? Is there any other "good" solution?

**- Second**: I don´t want a graphic interface in the program. And better if word and excel are in background as well. Any idea to accomplish this?
I suppose the only solution is option B), with the program as a windows service. Excel, word... will be in another "session", and it will not show anything (I´ve read antoher stackoverflow about this and the problem and solution to get excel and word work)

Comment: What about option C: have the .NET program do its tasks, running in low priority to not burn the CPU, and write its progress into database or shared text file? This way the classic ASP can read from the database or shared file and display the progress.

Comment: Yes, in fact I have thought the .NET program to run as a windows service, and read each second a table of jobs in a SQL server. When a task is submitted in the webpage (asp), is sent to the table of jobs. The next time the windows service read this table, it will change the status of the job as "Processing", and it will do all the tasks. When it finish, it will delete the job. About the progress, it´s a good idea, although you have to know the "% completed" in some places of the code. But I think I can estimate it.

Answer (score 0):

B is the better option, but I don't have any experience with MSMQ. You may want to use WCF+MSMQ since if it turns out MSMQ was the wrong option, it is possible to try some other protocol with less re-write.

As for option A, neither ASP classic or ASP.NET is optimized for dealing with long running processes. Browsers close mid request, IIS can seize up, it's harder to throttle work loads, etc, etc. Also, if you have one ASP page, this implies you have others and including long running tasks in your website mean you run the risk of users not being able to access other unrelated pages while all the webservers threads are taken up dealing with the long running processes.

Comment: I also think B is the best option. About MSMQ, I have only experience with messages in MCF and Visual C++. I suppose it won´t be very hard. As for A, I though when you run a program from asp, it´s executed in the background and IIS forget about that process. I don´t want to wait to finish the program. Only that ASP run the program.